# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '<string>'

Tags: python, django

I have no idea what is going on and I have taken a look at many of the other stack examples and problems similar to this, but none are helping. I am trying to filter through a list of my objects in Django, and I am running to the issue mentioned in the title: "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'EE468'."

My models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=25)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    dept_name = models.ForeignKey('Department', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='dept_name', blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'course'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_id + ", " + self.title + ", " + self.dept_name + ", " + str(self.credits)

class Takes(models.Model):
    studid = models.ForeignKey(Student, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    course = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name="takes_course")
    sec = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name="takes_section")
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='semester', blank=True, null=True, related_name="takes_semester")
    year = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='year', blank=True, null=True, related_name="takes_year")
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'takes'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.studid_id}, {self.course_id}, {self.sec_id}, {self.semester_id}, {self.year_id}, {self.grade}"

class Teaches(models.Model):
    instid = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    course = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name="teach_course")
    sec = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name="teach_sec")
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='semester', blank=True, null=True, related_name="teach_sem")
    year = models.ForeignKey(Section, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='year', blank=True, null=True, related_name="teach_year")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'teaches'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.instid) + ", " + str(self.course_id) + ", " + str(self.sec_id) + ", " + str(self.semester_id)
```

my call that is throwing the error:

```
    profID = 12345
    sem = 1
    year = 2020

    for teaches in Teaches.objects.filter(id=profID, semester=sem, year=year):
        logging.info(teaches.course_id)
        for takes in Takes.objects.filter(sec_id=teaches.sec_id, course_id=teaches.course_id):
            if ( takes.course_id != teaches.course_id ): continue
            logging.info("takes: " + takes.course_id)
            logging.info(takes)
```

SOS I have never really used django before and I don't understand why this is being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/ProjectPath/EEProject/myapp/viewsApi.py", line 69, in F4
    for takes in Takes.objects.filter(sec_id=teaches.sec_id, course_id=teaches.course_id):
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1466, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1496, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1412, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1242, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 154, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'EE468'.
```

Comment: also I have tried course, course_id and course__id and they all give the same result

Comment: Trace shows that problem is in line 'for takes in Takes.objects...' so maby the problem is in teaches.sec_id or teaches.course_id

Comment: It can't be either of them either, as you the logging statement above of printing out teaches.course_id and they works fine. The fact that it is printing EE468 shows that that's fine thankfully, it's something to do with the takes.course, takes.course_id and takes.course__id.

Comment: ah double underscore '__' should be : for takes in Takes.objects.filter(sec__id=teaches.sec__id, course__course_id=teaches.course__course_id):. if Section uses standard id field not like your Course where you specify pk with course_id field. Or simple without referencing fields : for takes in Takes.objects.filter(sec=teaches.sec, course=teaches.course):

Comment: This solution still does not work. Putting a double underscore for the teaches.sec__id gives me an error saying there is no attribute "sec__id" for the teaches object (as there is not). and then I do sec__id=teaches.sec_id I get the same error as originally stated. When I try just sec=teaches.sec and course=teaches.course I get "Unknown column 'section.id' in 'field list'"